# Trouble using virtualenv to create Django app for Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv

I'm trying to find the instructions [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django#using_a_different_wsgi_server) to launch a Django project on Heroku.  I don't get very far.  When I try to create the `virtualenv` I get the following error:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages hellodjango

New python executable in hellodjango/bin/python
ERROR: The executable hellodjango/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/6.3' (should     be '/Users/username/Sites/hellodjango')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I've actually never used virtualenv before so could be doing something very simple wrong. I think it's pointing to the Enthought python installation, though I thought that I had switched the default python to MacPort's installation.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few similar questions on SO that I found when searching for that last error message you list.

One thing to try is specifying `/path/to/python virtualenv --no-site-packages hellodjango`  This would force virtualenv to use the MacPort (or other) installed version.

Comment: Thanks for the insight -- that didn't work specifically, but it gave me the idea to install a new version of virtualenv using MacPorts (which I should have thought of on my own), and that did the trick.  Thanks!